# Substring of filename in LaTeX

Tags: xstring

For filename "DoctorStrange.tex", I want to print the substring "Strange" dynamically inside the file. The following command does not work; what am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}

\StrBehind{\jobname}{Doctor}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the starred version `\StrBehind*`, see section 3.4 of the [package docu](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/generic/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf).

Comment: Woah! That solved my problem! Thankyou so much!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
% File name: DoctorStrange.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
    \StrBehind*{\jobname}{Doctor}% <---- Note the starred variant
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: strange]

Certain TeX commands like `\jobname` (as is in your case) expand into strings made of characters with catcodes 12 and 10, whereas ordinary letters from the alphabet is given catcode 11.

The `xstring` package commands, as noted in the [package documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/generic/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf) (Section 3.4, under Catcode and Starred Macros), take catcodes into account during comparisons, and so `Doctor` is not found in the `\jobname` because they have different catcodes.

To solve this, `xstring` package provides a starred variant of its commands, in this case `\StrBehind*{<strA>}{<strB>}`, which detokenizes the two string arguments, and as the documentation puts it:

> ...everything is converted into chars with "harmless" catcodes.

which will then yield the desired result, as above.

Comment: is there any `StrAfter`?

Answer (score 6):

The characters in `\jobname` are “stringified”, which roughly means that your input `Doctor` (where the characters are letters) is not the same as the `Doctor` in `\jobname` (where they are nonletters).

You can use the “agnostic” version of `\StrBehind` or a similar category code agnostic function of `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\nodoctor}{o}
 {
  \tl_set:NV \l_tmpa_tl \c_sys_jobname_str
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A Doctor } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_new:N #1
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\nodoctor

\nodoctor[\thisname]

\texttt{\meaning\thisname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the optional argument you can specify the name of a macro that will contain the name. If you prefer that the text is treated as letters, for subsequent comparisons, you can use `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` (actually a variant thereof):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\nodoctor}{o}
 {
  \tl_set:NV \l_tmpa_tl \c_sys_jobname_str
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A Doctor } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_new:N #1
    \tl_set_rescan:NnV #1 { } \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn { NnV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\nodoctor

\nodoctor[\thisname]

\texttt{\meaning\thisname}

\newcommand*{\checkthisname}{Strange}

\ifx\thisname\checkthisname SUCCESS\else FAILURE\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]