# Setting \section Counter From First Letters of \jobname

Tags: xstring, catcodes

related to [Substring of filename in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394015/substring-of-filename-in-latex) and [extract number from \jobname as counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400792/extract-number-from-jobname-as-counter) .

I am naming my filenames as `01-text1.tex`, `02-something.tex`, `03-blah.tex` and so on.  I would like to set my section counter according to the first two letters (digits).  something like

```
\setcounter{section}{\StrLeft{\jobname}{2}}
\addtocounter{section}{-1}
```

this was less than successful, probably catcodes :-(.  can someone please recommend the magical invokation that works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need an expandable command if you are going to inline it into `\setcounter` `xstring` commands are mostly not expandable.

```
\def\getprefix#1-#2\relax{#1}
\setcounter{section}{\expandafter\getprefix\jobname\relax}
```

should work.

While it is true that letters in `\jobname` have strange catcodes that isn't actually an issue here as the digits are the usual catcode 12.

Answer (score 4):

The usual problem: this is not expandable.

Workaround: compute the string beforehand:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\StrLeft{\jobname}{2}[\temp]
\setcounter{section}{\temp}
\addtocounter{section}{-1}

\section{Title}
text

\end{document}
```

Simpler solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\setcounter{section}{ \str_range:Nnn \c_sys_jobname_str { 1 } { 2 } }
\addtocounter{section}{-1}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
text

\end{document}
```

Of course there is a lower level solution, but much less fun:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup\def\welch#1#2#3\welch{#1#2}
\setcounter{section}{\expandafter\welch\jobname..\welch}
\addtocounter{section}{-1}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
text

\end{document}
```